# Form with radio button

Tags: php, html

I have this:

```
<td>
    <input id="sex" name="sexFemale" value="female" type="radio">
    <label for="sexFemale">
        Kvinna
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <input id="sex" name="sexBoth" value="both" checked="checked" type="radio">
    <label for="sexBoth">
        Båda
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <input id="sex" name="sexMale" value="male" type="radio">
    <label for="sexMale">
        Man
    </label>
</td>
```

I think I made this wrong, how should I use it?

`$_POST["sex"]` to get the value "male" or "female" or what they chosed

Comment: +1 for providing a "both" option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set their `name` attribute to "sex" and have them carry diffrerent values:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />Female<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />Male<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

the `name` of the radiobuttons has to be the same, not the id (the id *must* be unique)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give them the same `name` (the name of the radio button group) attribute and different `id` attributes to work:

```
<td>
  <label><input id="sexFemale" name="groupSex" value="female" type="radio">
  Kvinna</label>
</td>
<td>
  <label><input id="sexBoth" name="groupSex" value="both" checked="checked" type="radio">
  Båda</label>
</td>  
<td>
  <label><input id="sexMale" name="groupSex" value="male" type="radio">
  Man</label>
</td>
```

Comment: +1 For having put the input inside the label tag, thus causing the click on the text checks the radio

Answer (score 0):

i think than all radio button inputs in one group must have the same 'name' attribute:

Kvinna
    Båda
                    Man

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['sex'] returns are element value with name attribute "sex". For use it - set all radiobutons name to "sex".

Answer (score 0):

Just switch your `name` attributes with your `id` attributes. So instead of

```
<input id="sex" name="sexFemale" ...
```

just use

```
<input id="sexFemale" name="sex" ...
```